Use Web View with Android Automotive?
is it possible to use Web View with Android Automotive?
I am developing an Android app for Android Automotive in which I want to use a Web View.
According to some sources, that doesn´t work with Android Automotive. However, when I use the Automotive emulator I can still use a Web View properly.
Does anyone have any experience with that?

If you will be distributing your app via the Play Store to Android Automotive cars with Google Automotive Services (GAS), and a GAS emulator supports WebView, then my guess is that GAS-enabled cars will too. If you will be distributing to just your own cars, you already have people on hand who can confirm WebView availability. And if you are distributing to non-GAS partners, talk to them and ask them if their cars support WebView.

Adding on to this, the Compatibility Definition Document (CDD) requires that certified Android Automotive OS devices (which includes all GAS vehicles) support WebView: https://source.android.com/docs/compatibility/9/android-9-cdd#2_5_3_software. That's the Android 9 CDD, but the same requirement is included in newer versions as well.
